# Pivot geometry which is not comparable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have one query which I'm making pivot but in this table I have "geometry" data type which is not comparable. How can I fix this issue.

I'm receiving the following error:

> Msg 488, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>       Pivot grouping columns must be comparable. The type of column "GEOM" is "geometry", which is not comparable.

Query what I have tried:

```
SELECT es.Extraction_Date,
       es.Table_Name,
       es.Extraction_Type,
       es.Feature_Count
FROM Extraction_Statistics es
PIVOT(SUM(es.Feature_Count) 
      FOR es.Extraction_Type IN ([Start], [Insert], [Update], [Delete])) AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-select instead of the full table to exclude the column `GEOM` on the `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT
    PivotTable.Extraction_Date,
    PivotTable.Table_Name,
    [Start], [Insert], [Update], [Delete]
FROM (
    SELECT Extraction_Date, Table_Name, Extraction_Type, Feature_Count 
    FROM Extraction_Statistics
) es PIVOT (
    SUM(es.Feature_Count) 
    FOR es.Extraction_Type IN ([Start], [Insert], [Update], [Delete])
) AS PivotTable;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f174ec63e2d4133b0f06d217c44d5d91) (*comparison between your query and this solution*)

You also have to fix some issues with your current `SELECT` statement:

- On the `SELECT` you can only use columns from the pivot table (here `PivotTable`). The table defined as `es` isn't available after the pivot.
- Columns used for the pivot you can't use on the `SELECT` (here `Feature_Count` and `Extraction_Type`). Use the pivot columns instead: `[Start]`, `[Insert]`, `[Update]` and `[Delete]`

Comment: getting this error

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "es.Extraction_Date" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
The multi-part identifier "es.Table_Name" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
The multi-part identifier "es.Extraction_Type" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
The multi-part identifier "es.Feature_Count" could not be bound.

Comment: @Skorpion added some explanation and updated answer.